# Laravel 5 Payum provider not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, omnipay, payum

I have installed payum for laravel 5 but my providers are not updating correctly.

I added 'Payum\LaravelPackage\PayumServiceProvider' to app/config/app.php file.

```
'providers' => [
     ...      
     //All my providers
    'Payum\LaravelPackage\PayumServiceProvider',
],
```

also tried as

```
'providers' => [
     ...      
     //All my providers
     Payum\LaravelPackage\PayumServiceProvider::class,
],
```

anyway the error message i get whenever i try to use artisan to make a controller or any other thing is:

[image: error-message]

am i missing any configuration for the service provider? any help will be apreciated.

EDIT: i have created a new provider and stopped using the default provider.

i ran `php artisan make:provider PayumServiceProvider`

and into its register method pasted:

```
...
public function register()
{
    $this->app->resolving('payum.builder', function(\Payum\Core\PayumBuilder $payumBuilder) {
        $payumBuilder
        // this method registers filesystem storages, consider to change them to something more
        // sophisticated, like eloquent storage
        ->addDefaultStorages()

        ->addGateway('paypal_ec', [
            'factory' => 'paypal_express_checkout',
            'username' => 'EDIT ME',
            'password' => 'EDIT ME',
            'signature' => 'EDIT ME',
            'sandbox' => true
        ]);
    });
}
...
```

Still not working

Comment: How did you install the package? `composer require`?

Comment: did you create a serviceProvider for it inside `pp/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` ? like stated in the docs  https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/laravel/get-it-started.md

Comment: @ceejayoz yes sir. composer require payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp php-http/guzzle6-adapter

Comment: @Sletheren on the docs it also says: "or add to the default app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php register method", thats what i did

Comment: can someone please share a link to a working laravel 5 example using Payum?